# wpf toolkit datetimepicker how to change disabled style

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

How can i change the background and foreground of dateTimePicker from xceed WPF Toolkit when it is disabled? By default they are grey and black,respectively and i need white and gray...

I'll be gratefull for any help!

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that to change disabling style of an element (especially colors) you have to edit its **Template**. If you try to use a style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="xctk:DateTimePicker">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aquamarine"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

you will see that it has no effect on the **Foreground** property (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751990/how-to-change-disabled-background-color-of-textbox-in-wpf) question about textbox). You may extract default template for Xceed DateTimePicker with Blend and then fix it.

**Update**
Here is a full source of xaml with edited template (I paste comments for you):

```
<StackPanel>

    <CheckBox x:Name="IsEnabled" IsChecked="False"></CheckBox>
    <xctk:DateTimePicker IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=IsEnabled, Path=IsChecked}" Value="1.08.1999">
        <xctk:DateTimePicker.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <xctk:ButtonSpinner x:Name="PART_Spinner" AllowSpin="{TemplateBinding AllowSpin}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsTabStop="False" ShowButtonSpinner="{TemplateBinding ShowButtonSpinner}">
                                <!--I removed setters of Background and Foreground properties here-->
                                <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" AcceptsReturn="False" BorderThickness="0" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" MinWidth="20" Padding="0" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" TabIndex="{TemplateBinding TabIndex}" WatermarkTemplate="{TemplateBinding WatermarkTemplate}" Watermark="{TemplateBinding Watermark}">
                                    <xctk:WatermarkTextBox.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:WatermarkTextBox}">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1"/>
                                                <Border x:Name="MouseOverVisual" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="0">
                                                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF5794BF" Offset="0.05"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFB7D5EA" Offset="0.07"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFC7E2F1" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                                                </Border>
                                                <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="0">
                                                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF3D7BAD" Offset="0.05"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFA4C9E3" Offset="0.07"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFB7D9ED" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                                                </Border>
                                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_WatermarkHost" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding WatermarkTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Watermark}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <MultiTrigger>
                                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
                                                        <Condition Property="Text" Value=""/>
                                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_WatermarkHost" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </MultiTrigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="MouseOverVisual" Value="1"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="FocusVisual" Value="1"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                                                    <!--I changed Background setter value to White here-->
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="White"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </xctk:WatermarkTextBox.Template>
                                </xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
                            </xctk:ButtonSpinner>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="_calendarToggleButton" Background="White" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                                    <Binding Path="IsOpen" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                        <Binding.Converter>
                                            <xctk:InverseBoolConverter/>
                                        </Binding.Converter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                                <ToggleButton.IsEnabled>
                                    <Binding Path="IsReadOnly" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                        <Binding.Converter>
                                            <xctk:InverseBoolConverter/>
                                        </Binding.Converter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </ToggleButton.IsEnabled>
                                <ToggleButton.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                        <xctk:ButtonChrome x:Name="ToggleButtonChrome" CornerRadius="0,2.75,2.75,0" InnerCornerRadius="0,1.75,1.75,0" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderChecked="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}}}" RenderEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}}}">
                                                            <Grid>
                                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                                                <Grid x:Name="arrowGlyph" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="5">
                                                                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0,1C0,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 3,0 3,0 3,0 3,1 3,1 3,1 4,1 4,1 4,1 4,0 4,0 4,0 7,0 7,0 7,0 7,1 7,1 7,1 6,1 6,1 6,1 6,2 6,2 6,2 5,2 5,2 5,2 5,3 5,3 5,3 4,3 4,3 4,3 4,4 4,4 4,4 3,4 3,4 3,4 3,3 3,3 3,3 2,3 2,3 2,3 2,2 2,2 2,2 1,2 1,2 1,2 1,1 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,1z" Fill="Black" Height="4" Width="7"/>
                                                                </Grid>
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </xctk:ButtonChrome>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FFAFAFAF"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </ToggleButton.Style>
                            </ToggleButton>
                        </Grid>
                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_calendarToggleButton}" StaysOpen="False">
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" Padding="3">
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.BorderBrush>
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE8EBED" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Calendar x:Name="PART_Calendar" BorderThickness="0" DisplayDate="2014-05-14"/>
                                    <xctk:TimePicker x:Name="PART_TimeUpDown" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" ClipValueToMinMax="{Binding ClipValueToMinMax, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" FormatString="{TemplateBinding TimeFormatString}" Format="{TemplateBinding TimeFormat}" Maximum="{Binding Maximum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Minimum="{Binding Minimum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" WatermarkTemplate="{TemplateBinding TimeWatermarkTemplate}" Watermark="{TemplateBinding TimeWatermark}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </xctk:DateTimePicker.Template>
    </xctk:DateTimePicker>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with Blend, how can i do this? Well, Xceed is open-source, maybe i can find template source code?

Comment: well, i found template on codeplex, but it works in a very strange way, i can't find, where the background of textbox is set (tried wpfInspector on control). Maybe they have some resource brush(how can i find it?) ?

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy To extract template in Blend acivate your element and find Template property in Properties tab from the right side. Then press at the little rectangle and choose "Convert to Local Value" from the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution and just made such a thing:

```
            <xctk:DateTimePicker Grid.Column="3" Background="White" Grid.Row="0" MinWidth="120" Margin="2" 
                             Value="{Binding EditDateFrom, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                             IsReadOnly="{Binding IsFirst, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsFirst}" Focusable="{Binding IsFirst}">
```

So, instead of Enabled i now use ReadOnly with Focusable