# How to change disabled Textbox Background colour in WPF to transparent

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I wanted to change the disabled background of my Textbox to a semitransparent Gradientbrush (one part transparent the other not).
I found this older post to a almost identical topic: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751990/how-to-change-disabled-background-color-of-textbox-in-wpf)
The accepted answer worked for my, as long as I did not wanted to add any transparency to it. Instead the transparent part of the background turns to some shade of gray.

How can I fix this a nice and clean way, the Template form the [MS-Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms752068%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might do the trick, but they always look so awfully giant for such small issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to a different control. I added my owncallback to the IsEnabled property like this

```
static IconPresenter()
  {
     IconPresenter.IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(IconPresenter), new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsEnabledChanged)));
  }
```

And then I added in the code that I wanted to happen when the IsEnabled is changed

```
private static void OnIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     IconPresenter iconPresenter = (IconPresenter)sender;

     if ((bool)e.NewValue == false)
     {
        iconPresenter.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
     }
     else
     {
        iconPresenter.Fill = Brushes.Black;          
     }
  }
```