# Styling Custom User Control Disabled state

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I style the 'disabled' state of my custom user control? I'm not clear on how to style the various parts of my custom user control. For example my custom user control is made up of several components. So How can I target specific parts of the control in my global style sheet? Keeping in mind that i want it to restore to it's original color if it's enabled again.

Here is my custom user control code...

**VNode.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.VNode"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Backplate" Fill="Green" Width="100" Height="50" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Highlight"
                   Height="60"
                   Width="110" 
                   Fill="Transparent"
                   Stroke="White"
                   StrokeThickness="2"
                   RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6">
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Label" Text="Label" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100" Height="50"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**VNode.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for VNode.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class VNode : UserControl
    {
        public VNode()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public Brush BackplateColor
        {
            get { return Backplate.Fill; }
            set { Backplate.Fill = value; }
        }
        public string Text
        {
            get { return Label.Text; }
            set { Label.Text = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Style sheet**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">

    <Style x:Key="NodeStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:VNode}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Backplate" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Looks like you have to override the templates of each control in VNode, see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751990/how-to-change-disabled-background-color-of-textbox-in-wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751990/how-to-change-disabled-background-color-of-textbox-in-wpf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to create or override `Style` for each `Control`. It gives to you flexibility for alteration styles of your `Controls` from code-behind and it is a separation of concerns.

**For example, let's see style for `TextBlock` which changes its style depend on `IsMouseOver` or `IsEnabled` conditions:**

At the App.xaml file:

```
<Application x:Class="UWPWpfApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="VNodeTextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

At the form:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello World!:)" Style="{StaticResource VNodeTextBlock}"/>
```