# Change color of disabled textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have problem with changing color of disabled textbox. I have already 'foreground' property for my textbox when it is enabled. But I want to set another color when it is disabled. How can I achieve this?

---

@Harry

It's nothing special

XML

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,185,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" IsEnabled="False" Background="Blue" />

 <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,271,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btn1_Click"/>
```

CS:

```
  private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        txt1.IsEnabled = true;

    }
```

By default txt1 is disabled and has grey color. I want change this color.

I can operate only on colors of enabled texbox. Now is set to 'blue'

Comment: show some code please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change disabled background color of TextBox in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751990/how-to-change-disabled-background-color-of-textbox-in-wpf)

Comment: @MichaelMairegger

My  question applies to Windows 10 UWP. I read Your article before, Triggers are not supported in windows 10

Comment: @user3688227 Ok, then you can work with Bahaviors, or Converters I will provide soon

Comment: I've updated your question, please do not add details to questions using answers. Answers are for answers only

Answer (score 3):

You could work with `Behaviors`

```
public class ControlBackgroundColorBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{
    private Control _contentDialog;

    public void Detach()
    {
        _contentDialog.IsEnabledChanged -= OnIsEnabledChanged;
    }

    DependencyObject IBehavior.AssociatedObject { get; }

    public DependencyObject AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

    public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject)
    {
        AssociatedObject = associatedObject;
        _contentDialog = AssociatedObject as ContentDialog;
        _contentDialog.IsEnabledChanged += OnIsEnabledChanged;
    }

    public Brush DisabledForegroundColor { get; set; }

    private void OnIsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Equals(e.NewValue, true))
        {
            _contentDialog.Foreground= DisabledForegroundColor ;
        }
        else
        {
            _contentDialog.Foreground= (Brush)Control.ForegroundProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(Control)).DefaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And in XAML

```
<TextBox>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <yourNamespace:ControlBackgroundColorBehavior DisabledForegroundColor ="Red" />
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just edit [the Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx) of your *TextBox* - you will find there *VisualState* responsible for changes when control is disabled. You can change foreground, background, border - anything you want. A sample with background color changed to red:

```xml
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this feature. I have llitle problems with using this. Could You provide me a little in my case? When textbox is disabled, I want to color o  background was for example blue. When will enable text has to change to white.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to check when button is disabled then set the colour to what you need. so something like this

```
if(txt1.IsEnabled == true){
  //enable colour
}else{
  //set disable colour
}
```

OR

You can also set the colour inthe form load function.

so in the form load method set the colour.

```
txt1.button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

or forecolor

```
txt1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
```

Along these lines.

Comment: I can't see any of this properties ' BackColor ', 'ForeColor'. I'm using Windwos 10 UWP

Comment: Can you see this Background property?  txt1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);