# App.xaml style not applying to windows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want all textboxes in my application to have a dark grey background when they are disabled or read only. I have added a style to my App.xaml which I believe should apply the style throughout my app.

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="XXXX.Deployment.Utils.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XXXX.Deployment.Utils" >
<Application.Resources>
    <local:InvertBoolConverter x:Key="invertBoolConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

The style is applying in the design window but not when I actually run the application. I created a window with just a single textbox and set the IsEnabled property to False so I am not sure why this style would not be applied.

TestWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="XXXX.Deployment.Utils.TestWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XXXX.Deployment.Utils"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="200" Width="800">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Margin="2" IsEnabled="False" />
</StackPanel>
```

TestWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace XXXX.Deployment.Utils
{
    public partial class TestWindow : Window
    {
        public TestWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I launch the window from within a console application and use

```
TestWindow t = new TestWindow();
t.ShowDialog();
```

**EDIT**

I think this issue may be because the App.xaml build action is not 'ApplicationDefinition'. We have all our UI in a common utility class library so we get the error 'Library project file cannot specify ApplicationDefinition element'. Is it possible for us to have a global style for controls even if our UI is in a class library?

Comment: are you able to run your application succesfully or are you missing StartupUri from your App.xaml??

Comment: The app builds and runs successfully.

Comment: are your using visual studio or some other editor.. i have tried your code and it worked as expected...

Comment: I am using Visual Studio

Comment: your code works fine, just try <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--  Logic Goes Here  -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

Comment: can you try changing <Style TargetType="TextBox"> to
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >

Comment: I have tried both of the above comments and a combination of the two and neither work

Comment: It seams your App.xaml does not have effect. It it's class name written properly? Try to remove word "partial" from app.xaml.cs

Comment: I have removed the word partial and I get the error Duplicate Definition 'XXXX.Deployment.Utils.App'. possibly missing keyword partial.

Comment: error in which file App.xaml.cs or TestWindow.xaml.cs?? or are you missing </Window> at the end of your TestWindow.xaml file?

Comment: I get the error in App.xaml.cs when removing the word partial from the App.xaml.cs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change disabled background color of TextBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751990/how-to-change-disabled-background-color-of-textbox-in-wpf)

Comment: Your style works just fine, the problem is that the Background Color of disabled TextBoxes is defined in the Control Template. The one for `IsReadOnly` should work as it is.